# Unable to navigate to homepage after register with firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Im trying to navigate to homepage after login, this works, i followed this one tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ5Vrya3wCQ&t=307s

But, my problem is when i go to register button > register an user and it takes me straight to the login page but when I fill in the login forms and log in, nothing happens, i must to do a "hot restart" to see my homepage, it is as if some widget did not rebuild. So i should do any better clean way to do this statemanagement?

Main:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/screens/login_page.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/screens/plant_screen.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/screens/register_page.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/screens/shop_scree_page.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges)
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Plant Shop UI',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
        routes: {
          'registerpage': (context) => RegisterPage(),
          'loginpage': (context) => LoginPage(),
          'homepage': (context) => PlantScreen(),
        },
        
        //theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget with ChangeNotifier{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseuser = context.watch<User>();
    notifyListeners();
    if(firebaseuser != null) {
      notifyListeners();
      return ShopScreen(); 
    } else {
      notifyListeners();
      return LoginPage();
    }
  }
}
```

Authentication service:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';



class AuthenticationService with ChangeNotifier{
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();

  Future<String> signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      notifyListeners();
      return "Signed in";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  Future<String> signUp({String email, String password, BuildContext context}) async{
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      print('USUARIO REGISTRADO');
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'loginpage');
      return "Signed Up";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async{
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

LoginPage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>{
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 80),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 80),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Login',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              _emailForm(),
              _passwordForm(),
              _button(),
              _buttonRegister(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _emailForm() {
    return TextField(
      controller: emailController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: ('Email')),
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordForm() {
    return TextField(
      controller: passwordController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: ('Password')),
    );
  }

  Widget _button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Login'),
      onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false).signIn(
            email: emailController.text.trim(),
            password: passwordController.text.trim());
      },
    );
  }

  _buttonRegister() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Registrarse'),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'registerpage');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

RegisterPage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:plantsapp/services/authentication_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  RegisterPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 80),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 80),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Registrarse',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
              ),
              _emailForm(),
              _passwordForm(),
              _button(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _emailForm() {
    return TextField(
      controller: emailController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: ('Email')),
    );
  }

  Widget _passwordForm() {
    return TextField(
      controller: passwordController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: ('Password')),
    );
  }

  Widget _button() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text('Registrarse'),
      onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context, listen: false).signUp(
            email: emailController.text.trim(),
            password: passwordController.text.trim(),
            context: context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem and i want to share it with all. The problem was the navigator, you have to maintain the flow, my app starts on the LoginPage so i use Navigator to go to RegisterPage, so, i start the app in the RegisterPage without using any Navigator between and test it, and its sends me to the HomePage automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I would say that using provider package in this simplest scenario is not really necessary. Handling authentication state with Firebase can be easily achieved with `StreamBuilder` and `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`.
So instead of pushing pages with navigator and calling notifyListeners(), just make a streamBuilder which rebuilds whenever authentication state changes (firebase auth package handles simplest state management for you, providing you handy stream of User objects)

```
StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) return LoginScreen();
          return YourScreenForSignedUsersScreen();
        })
```

Comment: i just disabled the "AuthenticationWrapper" class in the main, and, i added the StreamBuilder method to "home:", and its the same, MUST use hot reload or hot restart to see the homepage, this happend ONLY WHEN i go to registerpage, i register an user, back to login, and try to loggin with that user, I press login and nothing, I have to do a hot restart or hot reload for it to show me the homepage ( ShopScreen() in this case).

Comment: When you register a new user it's automatically signed in, so you don't have to ask user for login again (or as I conclude from your message you maybe even can't do that).

Comment: Try to run your app without pushing the login screen after registration (haven't noticed that before). That definitely **can** cause your issue

Comment: I remove the push to the login in the registration, but nothing changes, the app keep in the registration screen, i must do a hot restart to show me the homepage now.. im trying things while im posting this but nothing works.. should i force to push to homepage after register? because the StreamBuilder seems like doesnt work after register an user

Comment: i want to add this: after add a force navigator replacenamed to "homepage" after register, if i press "back" system buttom, its back to another homepage, and then exit the app, its like, now its open  2 homepages, but when i didnt force it, the widget didnt rebuild for himself, i must run a "hot restart" to see the homepage without force a Navigator..

Comment: i found the solution @SzymonKowaliński , the problem was the Navigator its like you have to maintain the flow. I test it and works, my app starts on the loggin screen, so, when i go to register page i use one Navigator, i just start the app from the RegisterPage and try and IT WORKS, now its send me to the homepage automatically.